Android studio throws error could not find 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5'
Android studio throws error "could not find 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5'"
The device it throw's error is MacBook pro, with intel i7 processor and macOS (Sonoma 14.6). It works perfectly with M1, M2 and AMD processor. Is the issue with processor.
I have invalidated the caches.
And what is the proper fix for this.

JCenter is completely shut down, so remove all the repository and remove all dependencies that require this repository.

This is because jfrog bintray is Dead & JCenter is shut down completely.
Solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/78944979/11485806
